# How to generate stronger RSA host key in Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, ssh

How can I generate a new HOST SSH key for my Raspberry Pi using a 4096-bit key (on Raspian Stretch)? I've read any number of tutorials that explain how to regenerate the host SSH key, like this one:

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-regenerate-openssh-host-keys/

But using this method leaves me with a 2048-bit host key, as far as I can tell. I also found this question:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127926/generate-own-stronger-rsa-host-key-for-openssh

Which comes maddeningly close to answering my question, but never actually specifies how to generate the host key. If this is something I can't do (or shouldn't be doing), I'd like to understand why as well.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/471327/how-to-change-a-ssh-host-key

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sudo ssh-keygen -b 4096 -h -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key`

---

This will generate a 4096 bit host rsa key in the default location

In general host keys are generated with the `ssh-keygen -h` option.

Host keys needs to be copied to `/etc/ssh`, permissions changed to `644` for public key,  `600` for the private key, and owner changed to `root:root`.

Keep in mind, other authentication methods like `dsa` have their own host keys and will not be affected by the key change

`sudo ssh-keygen -A`

will generate (missing) keys using default options, I haven't found if it is possible to change the default options.

If you break something you can delete the key and run the command. This is what `dpkg` does during install.

*ref* [linked question from serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/471327/how-to-change-a-ssh-host-key)

Comment: Is there any reason why I shouldn't just use a full pathname in the command instead of running/moving? In other words, just use the command

`sudo ssh-keygen -b 4096 -h -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key`

and then attend to the owner & permissions?

Comment: @madman Nope, no reason at all why you can't do that. In fact the permissions will likely be correct and the owner already root, I left that info in because SSH is very picky about permissions so if you are having problems its the first thing to check

Comment: Okay, I ran the single-line command that I referenced in my comment and everything has worked as advertised -- thanks so much for this! I was very close, even managing to get the -h option, but I couldn't quite connect the dots by putting the output in the global ssh space (`/etc/ssh`). One thing I noticed though: the owner is root, the private key has permissions `600`, but the public key has permissions `644` instead of the `640` that you suggested. Should I change this manually to `640`, or trust that ssh-keygen knows what it's doing and leave it at `644`?

Comment: That is my mistake,  `644` is the right permission - R/W by user root, readable by all , `640`  readable only by members of group "root". Since it is a public key  it is safe to be readable, and since it may need to be read by other users,  it is reasonable to give read permissions. 
 However, there may be cases were you would choose to lock it down. Commonly, personal ssh keys under `$HOME/.ssh`  are not publically readable.

Comment: Thanks for the clear, concise, and informative answer(s). I tried to upvote your answer, but apparently I'm not trustworthy enough to do this :-)